# Cronjob PHP script don't works

Tags: cron, centos7

I've tried several suggestions here on the site, but I couldn't, that's why I'm opening this question.

I created a cronjob (CENTOS7), with the following:

`***** /usr/bin/php /var/www/domain.com/html/v1/backend/files/teste.php`

But it doesn't run, but if I run the command below it works:

`php /var/www/domain.com/html/v1/backend/files/teste.php`

Comment: you can log the error by this `***** /usr/bin/php /var/www/domain.com/html/v1/backend/files/teste.php >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1`.to debug if the cron meet error

Comment: tks @nay, the cron.log was created, but the file is empty and the script don't run.

Comment: I got a new message when checking the status:

**/usr/bin/php) ERROR (getpwnam() failed**

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: how do you setup cronjob?can you test you cron with simple command like `* * * * * 
 echo "hello world" >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1`